# Which Vue handler is called?

Tags: vue.js

If one function is bound to multiple Vue event hooks, is there any way to know which event triggered the function?

Here's a contrived example:

```html
<div v-on:click="handler" v-on:mouseover="handler">
    Which event called handler? Click or Mouseover?
</div>
```

This could also help understand the context for Transition hooks and determining which was triggered.

```html
<transition appear v-on:appear="handler" v-on:enter="handler">
```

From inside `handler`, can we tell which hook was the caller?

A practical workaround for these situations would be decorating common functionality behind two simple wrapper functions, but it seems like Vue probably has a way of understanding its event calling context which might have been overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

The event object's `type` will tell you which event triggered the handler. You can get the event object in Vue using the [$event variable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers):

```js
Vue.component('demo', {
  template: '<div v-on:click="handler($event)" v-on:mouseover="handler($event)">Click or hover on me</div>',
  methods: {
    handler(e) {
      console.log(e.type); // e is the event object passed in as $event
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <demo></demo>
</div>
```